# Re-Generate Database class

Tags: java, netbeans, javadb

I have a database and a Frame the frame uses auto generated code Created by Net-beans(I bound a table to my database and then deleted the table to get the auto-generated code) to Insert records to a database I added another field to my table to my database the methods in the auto generated class however does not update itself to take into account the new field

```
    int idNO = 1;
    String email = txfEmail.getText();
    String name = txfName.getText();

    Usertbl obj = new Usertbl();
    Date created;

    obj.setName(name);
    obj.setEmail(email);
    for (Usertbl usertbl : usertblList) {
        idNO++;
    }

    obj.setId(idNO);

    PatDbPUEntityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    PatDbPUEntityManager.persist(obj);
    PatDbPUEntityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

ReBinding the table Helped but since the table Had been Deleted I recreated the table and Then deleted all automatically generated code and Bound the Table again.